# How to load local parquet files into GPDB?

Tags: greenplum

I made a GPDB cluster(5.18.0), and wanted to load some local parquet files into GPDB. How to acheive it? As I known gpload just supports plain and cvs file loading.

Is there any way even deprecated one to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GP 5.18, you need to look at using PXF as the mechanism to load parquet files.   Here is the link to the overview in the documentation:

https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5180/pxf/overview_pxf.html

That has links on how to configure PXF and actually load the data with PXF.  Check the section on Accessing Hadoop files - the section on parquet is in there.

Regards,
Jim McCann
Pivotal Software

Comment: I tried the pxf configuration with hdfs before, but failed. I don't think the doc can lead to successfully visiting to hdfs. GP5.18 itself brings 2.8.5 hdfs support, while our hdfs is based on 2.6.0 hadoop hdfs. I had done step by step according to the doc tourial , and restarted pxf service on each segment host, and still got several kinds of exception: No Class Found for xxxx, No such method for yyyy...

Answer (score 0):

You can install parquet-tools in all segment servers and use gpfdist and "command-based" web external table to extract parquet data. 
Greenplum web external table let you run script from segment servers to gpfdist server.

Answer (score 0):

gphdfs can also be used to load Parquet data into Greenplum. https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/580/admin_guide/external/g-hdfs-parquet-format.html

What is your Hadoop distribution?

Comment: We have a custom hadoop based on apache hadoop 2.6.0